# PHP javascript refresh div breaks page with multiple timers after setInterval runs

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a page fetching multiple data for a table. One of the data columns has a date and time value
from where a countdown timer runs.Each row has it's own countdown timer and it's working well.

However after I included javascript code to refresh the table after every 10 seconds and get new records inserted into the database, the page breaks and only displays the first timer in the countdown column timers. The tables uses datatable js library. Any recommended way that can enable the page div container to load the page correctly with javascript setinterval function will be highly appreciated.
The code below is what I use for refreshing the page div container

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    var url = "loaded.php";
    $('#loaded_orders').load(url + " #loaded_orders").fadeIn('slow');
  }, 10000);
});
```

This code I use to start the count down timer in the table columns. The table is wrapped in the div with the id "loaded_orders"

```
<table class="table table-bordered table stripped table hover" data-order='[[ 0, " desc" ]]' id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID </th>
          <th>Order No</th>
          <th>Order title</th>
          <th>Actual Deadline</th>
          <th>Assigned Writer</th>
          <th>Inserted By</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>ID </th>
          <th>Order No.</th>
          <th>Order title</th>
          <th>Actual Deadline</th>
          <th>Assigned Writer</th>
          <th>Inserted By</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          //echo json_encode($row); 
        ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= $row['id']; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $row['orderno']; ?></td>
            <td> <?= $row['ordertitle']; ?> </td>
            <td>
              <script src="./js/countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
              <script>
                u_d = ("d" + "<?= $row['id']; ?>");
                u_h = ("h" + "<?= $row['id']; ?>");
                u_m = ("m" + "<?= $row['id']; ?>");
                u_s = ("s" + "<?= $row['id']; ?>");
                ty = "<?= $row['actdeadline']; ?>";

                document.write("<div class='writerDeadl'><p class='timer'><span id='" + u_d + "'></span> Day(s) <span id='" + u_h + "'></span>:<span id='" + u_m + "'></span>:<span id='" + u_s + "'></span></p></div>");

                countdown(ty, u_d, u_h, u_m, u_s);
              </script>
            </td>
            <td><?= $row['asswriter'];  ?> </td>
            <td><?= $row['inserted_by']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="details.php?details=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-primary p-2" target="_blank">Details</a> |
              <a href="includes/action.php?deleted=<?= $row['id']; ?>&page=loaded" class="badge badge-danger p-2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Record?');">del<i class="fas fa-trash "></i></a> |
              <a href="edit_order.php?edit=<?= $row['id']; ?>&page=loaded" class="badge badge-secondary p-2">Edit<i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a> |
              <a href="includes/action.php?send=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-success p-2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to send this order?');">send<i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></a> |
              <a href="includes/action.php?scancel=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-dark p-2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel this order?');">cancel</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The code below is for countdown.js file

```
function countdown(endDate, uid_d, uid_h, uid_m, uid_s) {
let timer, days, hours, minutes, seconds;

endDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();
if (isNaN(endDate)) {
    return;
}

if (uid_d != null) {
    timer = setInterval(calculate, 1000);
}

function calculate() {
    let startDate = new Date();

    startDate = new Date(
        startDate.getUTCFullYear(),
        startDate.getUTCMonth(),
        startDate.getUTCDate(),
        startDate.getUTCHours(),
        startDate.getUTCMinutes(),
        startDate.getUTCSeconds()
    );

    let timeRemaining = parseInt((endDate - startDate.getTime()) / 1000);

    if (timeRemaining >= 0) {
        days = parseInt(timeRemaining / 86400);
        timeRemaining = timeRemaining % 86400;

        hours = parseInt(timeRemaining / 3600);
        timeRemaining = timeRemaining % 3600;

        minutes = parseInt(timeRemaining / 60);
        timeRemaining = timeRemaining % 60;

        seconds = parseInt(timeRemaining);

        document.getElementById(uid_d).innerHTML = parseInt(days, 10);
        document.getElementById(uid_h).innerHTML = ("0" + hours).slice(-2);
        document.getElementById(uid_m).innerHTML = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
        document.getElementById(uid_s).innerHTML = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the only way to refresh datatables with setInterval without losing datatbles functionality is to use json data then draw the table. After ding that everything is working well.